# intercepting http request before csurf validation

Tags: javascript, express, csrf

Is there a way to intercept a http call before the csurf validation. I have the below code

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var express = require('express')

// create express app
var app = express()

// create api router
var api = createApiRouter()

// mount api before csrf is appended to the app stack
app.use('/api', api)

// now add csrf and other middlewares, after the "/api" was mounted
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))

app.get('/form', function (req, res) {
  // pass the csrfToken to the view
  res.render('send', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})

app.post('/process', function (req, res) {
  res.send('csrf was required to get here')
})

function createApiRouter () {
  var router = new express.Router()

  router.post('/getProfile', function (req, res) {
    res.send('no csrf to get here')
  })

  return router
}
```

I want to log the CSRF token sent by the client for troubleshooting an error I am getting. But I was not able to find a way to intercept the request before it is sent for CSRF validation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by adding the following code

```
var logToken = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Token: ', res.get('x-xsrf-token');
    next();
};
app.use(logToken);
```

I added this code before configuring the csrf token and after configuring the cookie parser.